# Dartime Format (nome do mês com letra minuscula)

Tags: flutter

Estou formatando a seguinte data "2020-03-25" e quero que ela saia "25 de Março" porem com minha formatação ela esta saindo "25 de março" o nome do mês esta saindo com letra minuscula, é possível arrumar?

```
String dateFormate = DateFormat("dd' 'MMMM", 'pt_BR').format(2020-03-25);
```

Answer (score 1):

Após olhar a [Documentação da classe DateFormat](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html), nenhum outro parâmetro parece fazer o que você deseja. Essa informação de "maiusculização" parece vir diretamente de quando você seleciona o locale `pt_BR`.

Porém, você pode fazer uma função para tal:

```
String tornarMesMaiusculo(String data){
    List<String> palavras = data.split(" ");
    palavras.last = "${palavras.last[0].toUpperCase()}${palavras.last.substring(1)}";
    return (palavras.join(" "));
  }
```

Se preferir, pode fazer uma `extension` para poder chamar diretamente:

```
extension mesMaiusculo on String{

  String tornarMesMaiusculo(){
    List<String> palavras = this.split(" ");
    palavras.last = "${palavras.last[0].toUpperCase()}${palavras.last.substring(1)}";
    return (palavras.join(" "));
  }
}
```

Assim irá poder chamar diretamente:

```
String dateFormate = '25 de março';
print (dateFormate.tornarMesMaiusculo()); // imprime "25 de Março"
```

Não se esqueça que uma função desse tipo presume a String ser dessa forma específica, e você deve tomar as precauções para não chamá-la com strings vazias por exemplo.